# How do you enable RAID in the Jaunty Live CD (in order to change partitions)?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, raid, ubuntu-9.04, livecd

I need to increase the size of my Karmic Koala partition, but I believe I can't do that from within the system itself. The CD I have is from Jaunty, which does not support RAID out of the box. How do I install/enable RAID HDD detection in the Jaunty live CD in order that I may change the system's partition size? (or is there an easier way to go about this?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must install needed packages for raid support: `sudo apt-get install dm-raid mdadm`

Then you enable kernel module for raid by issuing `sudo modprobe dm-raid4-5`. This should also load `dm-mod`.

After that you can verify whether the raid device is automatically found by issuing `ls /dev/md*`. (Or replacing *md* with anything your raid device is named - can be found with `fgrep ARRAY /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, unless your */etc* is stored on that raid...) If the listing shows no devices, they can be scanned automatically via `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan`.

And, as a final step, mount the filesystem(s): `sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt` or similar.

(Note, that these instructions are based on experiences with 8.10 so some steps might be unnecessary on 9.04.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Linux live CD to mess with your RAID and/or partitions, provided it supports it.

Personally I use [Finnix](http://www.finnix.org/) which is nice and small, but command line only (good enough for me). If you want a graphical one, try something like [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.org/).